# What is control registers in cpu?

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu, processor

> A control register is a processor register which changes or controls
>   the general behavior of a CPU or other digital device. Common tasks
>   performed by control registers include interrupt control, switching
>   the addressing mode, paging control, and coprocessor control.
>   - from Wikipedia

Below are my doubts

- Is control registers are set of instructions? Can we say `interrupt control` is the interrupt control routine which has a mapping of interrupt and associated routine?

Just trying to understand how control registers basically work whether it is a set of instructions executed by CPU when needed or they are hardware chips works parallel with CPU or any other.

Kindly explain to me using `interrupt control`.

Comment: think of CPU as a application which perform some algorithm and those registers as a set of parameters (variables) which control the flow of this application, like gmail has tons of control registers which affect behavior like whether forward email or not. When we are masking interrupts via setting some value to register CPU starts ignoring signals on specific lines and so on.

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to understand because of strange grammar. A control register is a register which you can write or read as any other register, but writing it will have an effect on the general behavior of the CPU. An interrupt control register could be used to enable or disable interrupts generally or for certain interrupt sources. It can also contain information about pending interrupts which has to be reset by the interrupt handler. Details depend on the CPU you are using and should be found in the corresponding manuals.

Comment: tnx MaximSagaydachny, Bodo for your response